# easiest way to find user's locale currency

Tags: php, http, server, locale

I have a website with american and europeans clients. I need to find a way to switch between Euros and USD depending on the client's localisation. Euros for Europeans and USD for the rest of the world.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` is not an option since it returns FR for French-Canadians who are using Dollar and not Euros.

I would like to avoid having to install libraries (if possible) since I never did that before.

Comment: For those pesky Canadiens, is it only returning "fr", or is it returning "fr-ca"?

Comment: language != currency or country

Comment: i am one of those pesky canadians :P it's returning fr-fr, it may depend on the language you select during windows installation, and i suppose most french canadians use standard french language file, since there is no difference between canadian french and french from france (like the difference between US english and GB)

Comment: You cannot do that by means of looking at language things. You need some geolocation solution, so a library. And even that is not precise. IN the end you have to allow switching the currency anyway.